# \href{} problem on moderncv document class

Tags: hyperref, moderncv

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{hyperref}    

\begin{document}
\cvitem {some text}{\href{url}}{text}
\end{document}
```

The problem I get is:

```
Option clash for package hyperref
```

and also a second error:

```
Paragraph ended before \\cvitem was complete.
```

What have I made wrong?

Comment: `moderncv`already loads `hyperref` package with certain options. Hence this error.. If you want to make some changes, please use `\hypersetup`. No need of loading `hyperref` again.

Comment: I corrected `doument` to `document` as it was clearly a typo. But your code remains uncompilable. AFAIK the command `\cvitem` has just two arguments. You use three here. Please have a look on some other examples in order to learn the right syntax and do not load `hyperref` a second time.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi And `\href` has two arguments missing one. Thus, moving the second curly closing brace to the end after `{text}` is probably the solution: `\cvitem{some text}{\href{url}{text}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`moderncv` loads `hyperref` package by itself with the option `unicode`. These are the lines from `moderncv.cls`.

```
\AtEndPreamble{
  \pagenumbering{arabic}% has to be issued before loading hyperref, as to set \thepage and hence to avoid hyperref issuing a warning and setting pdfpagelabels=false
  \RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}% unicode is required for unicode pdf metadata
  \hypersetup{
    breaklinks,
    baseurl       = http://,
    pdfborder     = 0 0 0,
    pdfpagemode   = \pdfpagemode,
    pdfstartpage  = 1,
    pdfcreator    = {\LaTeX{} with 'moderncv' package},
%    pdfproducer   = {\LaTeX{}},% will/should be set automatically to the correct TeX engine used
    bookmarksopen = true,
    bookmarksdepth= 2,% to show sections and subsections
    pdfauthor     = {\@firstname{}~\@lastname{}},
    pdftitle      = {\@firstname{}~\@lastname{}\notblank{\@title}{ -- \@title}{}},
    pdfsubject    = {Resum\'{e} of \@firstname{}~\@lastname{}},
    pdfkeywords   = {\@firstname{}~\@lastname{}, curriculum vit\ae{}, resum\'{e}}}}
```

Hence, if you load the package again, the error

```
Option clash for package hyperref
```

is generated. Hence remove the line `\usepackage{hyperref}` from your file. On the other hand, if you want to change some settings for `hyperref`, use `\hypersetup` at appropriate place in your file.

Similarly the `\cvitem` is defined as (in `moderncv.cls`)

```
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{}
```

which means, `\cvitem` takes three arguments and the first argument is optional. The first argument is actually the space between the `\cvitem`s with default being `0.25em`. But you are using three arguments with all three being mandatory (enclosed in braces `{}`). Remove one argument.